# Blazor: two-way bind error - work only first time

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, matblazor

I have next code:

```
@foreach (var h in FStrings)
{   
    <input @bind-value="@h.FilterText" />
    <button @onclick="@(()=>Filter(h.Name, h.FilterText))"></button>
}
```

When I enter text for the first time, everything works fine: the function 'Filter' receives the entered value. But next time that I would not enter all the time, the value changes to the first entered.
Tell me what to change? 
Thank!

Comment: some reading for you here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding

Comment: I can not see a problem with your code - it works for me.

Comment: Hi Anna, could you reword this part "But next time that I would not enter all the time, the value changes to the first entered" to explain the issue in a bit more detail, or maybe add a gif showing what's happening?